# Unable to locate the Javac Compiler

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu, compilation, classpath

I tried to `mvn install` and got this message:

```
Compilation failure
Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:
  /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/../lib/tools.jar
Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and
not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required).
In most cases you can change the location of your Java
installation by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
```

Well, there is an open jdk, I also downloaded another one. I tried to point JAVA_HOME to both, now it is set:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_03
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export PATH
```

I also tried to choose one of those open with `sudo update-alternatives --config java` but got the same error with different jdk versions in it.

How can I fix that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's the output of "javac -version" and "which javac"?

Comment: @Korgen After the "javac -version" I got "The program 'javac' can be found in the following packages" and a suggestion to install one of them (well, there was an open jdk there which is installed already).

Comment: Have you logged in and out since?

Comment: @dave00 Logged in the Ubuntu since installing? No, I didn't.

Comment: @dave00 OMG thanks, I logged in again and it seems to be running fine, I'll write if it works

Answer (score 19, accepted):

it seems like your PATH is not picked up correctly... does the output of "echo $PATH" contain the directory where javac resides?
I would suggest following:

open terminal and do an:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_03
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
javac -version
which javac
```

if javac -version still does not work create a symlink in /usr/local/bin pointing to your javac binary:

```
cd /usr/local/bin
ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_03/bin/javac javac
```

this should get you up an running...
an alternative is to try setting up java via your package management system (e.g. "apt-get install java" or sth. similar)

Comment: Thanks, now I get the javac version, but I still get the compilation failure

Comment: are you executing maven from the same terminal as where you entered the above lines? Is the mvn error message still refering to the openjdk directory or to /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_03?

Comment: See question's comments, problem seems to be solved, but thanks anyway, I'll mark this answer as soon as it's good.

Answer (score 6):

I faced similar error on an ubuntu machine while running a maven build from Jenkins. If output of 'javac -version' prompts below messages:

"The program 'javac' can be found in the following packages: 
  default-jdk
  ecj
  gcj-5-jdk
  openjdk-8-jdk-headless
  gcj-4.8-jdk
  gcj-4.9-jdk
  openjdk-9-jdk-headless
Try: apt install "

Then you can install "openjdk-8-jdk-headless" using:

## apt install openjdk-8-jdk-headless

This solved my problem and the maven build went through ok.