# Running Maven web application to Tomcat

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat, build, m2eclipse

I have a problem with Tomcat when I run my web application. Here is the relevant part of my `pom.xml` :

```xml
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>7</version>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

When I run with **m2eclipse** (`tomcat:run`) I have this error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:jar:7 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:7: Plugin org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:7 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:jar:7
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building ourtest 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:jar:7 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:7: Plugin org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:7 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:jar:7
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:run (default-cli) @ ourtest >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ ourtest ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\user\Documents\EclipseProjects\ourtest\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ ourtest ---
[INFO] Compiling 7 source files to C:\Users\user\Documents\EclipseProjects\ourtest\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:
  C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\..\lib\tools.jar
Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and
not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required).
In most cases you can change the location of your Java
installation by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.317s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Mar 05 15:50:20 GMT+01:00 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project ourtest: Compilation failure
[ERROR] Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:
[ERROR] C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\..\lib\tools.jar
[ERROR] Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and
[ERROR] not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required).
[ERROR] In most cases you can change the location of your Java
[ERROR] installation by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I tested a lot of configurations in `pom.xml` but to no result.

Comment: Try with a JDK and not just a JRE. Check your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable. Also your eclipse.ini sometimes needs to be modified to use a JDK and not JRE.

Comment: how to make theses changes

Answer (score 4):

Try changing two things:

1) Update the tomcat7-maven-plugin version to 2.1

2) Use "mvn tomcat7:run"

The version specified doesn't exist and the command you are using will run the old codehaus plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the [FAQ](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/M2ECLIPSE/Project+FAQ#ProjectFAQ-UnabletolocatetheJavacCompilerError) related to this issue for M2Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

To check Your JAVA_HOME environment variable You need to type in the command line (WIN)
java --version. This can tell You if Your sys. using JDK or JRE. You can also go to MyComputer -> Properties -> Advanced -> environment variables and see on the list what JAVA_HOME is(I don't use the english ver. of Win so the names might be a little diferent).
To change JRE in Eclipse(I'm using Juno) go to Project Properies -> Java Build Path -> Libraries Tab -> Add a JDK lib if not present.

Answer (score 0):

Maven is looking for compiler probably in a JRE instead of a JDK make sure that you set the class path to a JDK

[Unable to locate the Javac Compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812668/unable-to-locate-the-javac-compiler)